# Why data types was changed while calling the apply function in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

While using the apply function to process a DataFrame, the data type of columns was changed unexpectedly. What should I do to prevent this?

For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [3]: tmp = DataFrame({'item':[1,2,3]})

In [4]: tmp['score'] = 0.0

In [5]: tmp.dtypes
Out[5]:
item       int64
score    float64
dtype: object

In [6]: tmp
Out[6]:
   item  score
0     1    0.0
1     2    0.0
2     3    0.0

In [7]: def Test(x):
   ...:     return x
   ...:

In [8]: tmp = tmp.apply(Test,axis=1)

In [9]: tmp.dtypes
Out[9]:
item     float64
score    float64
dtype: object
```

The data type of `tmp['item']` was changed into float. How to maintain the original data type of it?

Comment: Some of the data in the DataFrame is missing. Check line#3.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `.apply` essentially iterates over rows (when axis=1) and applies the function to a Series that represents each row. Since `Series` must contain the same data type, a Series made from a row of mixed `int` and `float` types will properly promote `ints` to `float`:

```
In [4]: def test(x): return x

In [5]: tmp.iloc[0]
Out[5]: 
item     1.0
score    0.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64

In [6]: tmp.apply(test, axis=1)
Out[6]: 
   item  score
0   1.0    0.0
1   2.0    0.0
2   3.0    0.0
```

Note what happens when we select a column, though:

```
In [7]: tmp.iloc[:,0]
Out[7]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: item, dtype: int64

In [8]: tmp.apply(test, axis=0)
Out[8]: 
   item  score
0     1    0.0
1     2    0.0
2     3    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to assign `tmp['score']` according to the corresponding  `tmp['item']` value (i.e. use `tmp['item']` to find values in other DataFrame, and use that value to calculate `tmp['score']`) in Test function and do not want to change `tmp['item]`'s data type?

Comment: Although I'm looking for a better solution, simply use `int()` function to force the type casting in Test function is OK. Thanks.

Comment: @ZhihongDeng I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish exactly, so it's hard to say. However, `tmp['item']` data type doesn't change. `apply` returns a new data structure.